# Visual Studio - Cannot validate since a PHP installation could not be found, FTP to server

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I get the error when I open my VS. I´m working with, or on, files directly on the server, using SimpleFTP to synch between computer/Server. That means the files are loaded, and saved, directly from/to my server (yes, they are cached om the computer...).

This also means that a have the PHP installed on the server - not my computer/PC. Is it possible to use the server-installation of PHP, or do I need to install a PHP extension on my PC?

If I can use the server PHP installation - How do I set the path? I´m running Raspberry/Apache...

Hopefull for any respons...

Comment: No, it's not possible to run the PHP installation on the FTP server locally. You should _really_ change your workflow and set up a development environment on your local computer. Then you write _and test_ the code locally before you send it up to the production server. Changing the code directly on the production server should never be done! It's madness for many reasons! Not only is it easy to break your public site that way, but you can also more easily accidentally expose sensitive data while debugging.

Comment: Hi! - and thanks for your reply! I hear you, and I even might follow your recommendations... It´s a local server, set up for testing - so it´s not open for the public - but I hear you. Will look inte another way of working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using FTP you can only transfer/sync files. For running `php` command line is necessary. Better approach is to use `ssh`. On `vscode` using [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) official extension you can access complete developer environment.